# Run a bash command after some simultaneous commands?

Tags: bash, shell-script, background-process

I want to run some commands in parallel. When all of these commands are finished start the next one. I though the following approach will work

```
#!/bin/bash
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &&
command4
```

but it didn't. I need to run `command4` when all the first three commands have been completely finished.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
command1 &
command2 &
command3 &

wait
command4
```

`wait` (without any arguments) will wait until all the backgrounded processes have exited.

The complete description of `wait` in the `bash` manual:

> `wait [-n] [n ...]`
>
> Wait for each specified child process and return its termination
>                 status.  Each `n` may be a process ID or a job specification; if a
>                 job spec is given, all processes in that job's pipeline are
>                 waited for.  **If `n` is not given, all currently active child
>                 processes are waited for, and the return status is zero.**  If the
>                 `-n` option is supplied, `wait` waits for any job to terminate and
>                 returns its exit status.  If `n` specifies a non-existent process
>                 or job, the return status is 127.  Otherwise, the return status
>                 is the exit status of the last process or job waited for.

Comment: Another option is to save the PID of each child using something like `PID1=$!` and then wait for all of them with `wait "$PID1" "$PID2" "$PID3"`. That is slightly more complicated, but will work if the process has other children which you do not want to wait for.

Comment: @kasperd Better with a array in that case: `cmd1 & pids=( $! ); cmd2 & pids+=( $! ); cmd3 & pids+=( $! ); wait "${pids[@]}"` or something similar.

Comment: @kasperd By "better" I mean "uses only one variable". Nothing inherently wrong with using many, and is probably totally ok for small cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `wait` answer, but just as an academic exercise, I think this would also work:

```
bash -c 'command1 & command2 & command3 &' && command4
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Did you test this?  It absolutely does not work.  Example: `time bash -c "sleep 5 &sleep 5 &sleep 5 &" && echo foo`  If it doesn't say  the bash command took five seconds, it didn't do what you want.

Comment: I tested it with sleep and echos and it seemed to work. Your example proves otherwise.